# Shell command not asking for password inside while loop

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to run .sh file to put certificate via keytool command in every jre/lib/security/cacert file described in ~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties file.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN=deployment\.javaws\.jre\.[0-9]*\.path
FILE=~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
sep='='
trail=lib/security/cacerts

#Traverse file line by line
while read line ; do

  #If line matches pattern
  if printf %s\\n "${line}" | grep -q "${PATTERN}"; then
    case $line in 
      (*"$sep"*)

        #Process line to get path for ../jre/lib/security/cacert file
        after=${line#*"$sep"};
        resultPath=${after%????????}${trail};

        #This fails : no password asked and IOException showed
        sudo bash -c keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias test-cert -file ./test.cer -keystore ${resultPath};

      ;;
      (*)
      ;;
    esac
  fi
done < "$FILE"
```

In line

```
sudo bash -c keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias test-cert -file ./test.cer -keystore ${resultPath};
```

Should be asking for passwords : 1st - admin password because of `sudo` and 2nd - `keystore` password. But when I run this script through  `bash ./script.sh`, the shell asks only for admin password and no `keystore` has asked. As a result. I have this error:

```
Enter keystore password:  keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:885)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
    ... 5 more
```

What should I do get asking for `keystore` password?

Comment: Close voters: I do not see why this question is considered off-topic. It looks fine to be. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you call the script? What's the content of `deployment.properties`? Has it worked at some point?

Comment: I think you have not set password for that and keystore isn't password protected.

Comment: @Braiam He says in his post that he calls the script with `bash ./script.sh`. This line makes me think it is an issue with his shell script somewhere, not in the Java stuff: `Should be asking for passwords : 1st - admin password because of sudo and 2nd - keystore password. But when I run this script through bash ./script.sh, the shell asks only for admin password and no keystore has asked. As a result. I have this error: `.

Comment: @Seth "Enter keystore password:  keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" is an error of the keytool, not the bash script. The bash script 'works' correctly (no syntax error) but without knowing what it tells to keytool (bash reads a file (which I asked the content of), and iterates it) to run, we are blind.

Comment: @Braiam If the script is not asking for a keystore 'password' then it is passing in nothing.

Comment: @Seth is not asking for a password because the "Keystore" is probably bad, invalid, doesn't exist or "tampered". We need to know exactly which is, so we could apply corrective measures.